# How to set default mount options in OS X?

Tags: mac-osx

I'm trying to figure out where the default mount options are set for user-mounted filesystems (e.g., disk images, USB thumbdrives, etc.). I'm working with OS X 10.11 ("El Capitan").

The options I specify for known disk partitions in `/etc/fstab` are respected when they're mounted automatically at boot time — or even manually via Disk Utility — but I can't seem to set the default mount options for anything automounted in /Volumes.

I've tried changing `AUTOMOUNTD_MNTOPTS` in `/etc/autofs.conf` and adding options with `-o` to the `ProgramArguments` array of `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.automountd.plist` (which required disabling SIP), but neither seems to have any effect.

It would seem that some other set of defaults is being used... but where are those defaults defined?

Comment: you might have better luck on our sister site http://apple.stackexchange.com/